# How to split a string which has numbers and increment a number by 1?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

so am dealing with invoices where in header number is something like this

"sab-0233"

so how do i split it and increase the number to 0234 and then concat again to make "sab-0234" for next header?

Comment: Please edit to show your work, and where you're having issues. Currently your question is just a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice function near '-' and then add 1 to the remaining string converting it into int and then concat it again using Concat function in compose connector. Below is the expression that worked for me.

```
concat(slice(outputs('Compose'),0,add(indexOf(outputs('Compose'),'-'),1)),add(int(slice(outputs('Compose'),add(indexOf(outputs('Compose'),'-'),1),length(outputs('Compose')))),1))
```

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi thank you for replying but i want 00 in the front too

Comment: @Ranaji, please modify your question too